# Storing JSON Value in javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON value to store in javascript array.

My JSON value :

```
"Users":[{"user_name":"User 1","id":1,"image_url":"/photos/list/missing.png","level":1,"position":{"name":"User ABC","description":"desc"}}]
```

I'm getting response in alert same as above.
Code:

```
alert("Response : " + $.toJSON(res["Users"]));
```

O/P : Response : [{"user_name":"User 1","id":1,"image_url":"/photos/list/missing.png","level":1,"position":{"name":"User ABC","description":"desc"}}]

Storing this value as
Code:

```
tempJSON = $.toJSON(res["Users"]);
```

`alert("JSON Array : " + tempJSON.length);`
`alert("Name : " + tempJSON[0]. user_name);`

O/P : JSON Array : 132 -> No. of characters.
Name : Undefined. -> Because it can't find value for "user_name"

If I'm Storing this value as Simple String.
Code:

```
tempJSON = [{"user_name":"User 1","id":1,"image_url":"/photos/list/missing.png","level":1,"position":{"name":"User ABC","description":"desc"}}];
```

`alert("JSON Array : " + tempJSON.length);`
`alert("Name : " + tempJSON[0]. user_name);`

Then Getting Exactly,

O/P :

JSON Array : 1 -> No. of Array.

Name : User 1

I don't getting what's going on.
Please tell me any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you're using the tempJSON as an object: `tempJSON[0]` will be the first character of the JSON string. If you need to access the object, you'll need to use `res.Users[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was consider whole value as a string

Code ::

```
var tempJSON = $.toJSON(res.Users[0]);
```

It's working.

Enjoy Coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
tempJSON = $.toJSON(res["Users"]);
```

=> you are getting a string in your tempJSON variable, not the object!

Maybe use firebug or any other developer tool to debug your JS.

Comment: Hey it's resolved by res.Users[0] value.
It's working fine. May be it was consider whole value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

While fetching the value in tempJSON you don't have convert the object to JSON(String).
Instead you try below code :-

```
var tempJSON = res["Users"];
```

For Your Reference:- [try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/jigneshparmar/vC89A/)